# Открытие рекламы при запуске программы

Tags: реклама

Как сделать так чтобы при запуске программы открывалась реклама в браузере, как сделано у многих приложений? Каким ресурсом можно воспользоваться для этого? Если что программирую на C++ платформа Windows, desktop приложение. Возможно есть более удачные идеи для создания рекламы в приложении?

Comment: отличный способ разогнать всех пользователей приложения и получить отдельный котел в аду :D Более эффективно только показывать рекламу на весь экран во время работы каждые 5 минут.

Comment: ну не знаю, мне кажется если просто запустить программу и откроется браузер с сайтом с рекламой, то можно просто его закрыть и все. Пользователи мою программу в день будут запускать от 1 до 3 раз и поэтому я не вижу в этом проблемы